# Sql Server does not start after server reboot

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server 2012 installed on Windows 2012.

The last five times the server rebooted, the SQL server did not start at system startup.

When I then log in as administrator, opened `services.msc` and try to start the "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" service manually, the error is

> Error 1069: The service did not start due to logon problems.

Every time, I have to click "Properties", "Log On", clear the password field, click "OK" and then I can start the SQL server service.

Why does the service always forget that the empty password is correct? How to fix?

I already tried a repair install of SQL server, but this didn't change the behaviour.

EDIT: I have found that this could be caused by [something or someone resetting the "Login As A Service" permission on that account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390921/sql-server-2012-cant-start-because-of-a-login-failure). The suspect named is GPO, but I did not find an [GPO Event 1502](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727320(v=ws.10).aspx) in the event log.

Comment: Don't use an empty password?

Comment: @Seth How can I set a password on the `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER` account?

Comment: [MSDN on Service User Accounts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686005(v=vs.85).aspx). The instructions are a bit obscure. Check the `lusrmgr.msc`. The Notation of your user is a bit strange. Is it NT Service or should it be MSSQLSERVER? Usually you identify a user using the domain. So e.g. MYSERVER\MSSQLSERVER or MYDOMAIN\MSSQLSERVER.

Comment: Alexander - Did you get this figured out yet? If not is this server joined to a domain and what credential or you running the SQL Server service as exactly? I wasn't sure if it was a local admin account, an AD service account or what. Check out https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions#Windows if you want just in case.

Comment: I did not get that figured out yet, no. Maybe it could be caused by Azure AD Connect running amok; it started shortly after we upgraded to the most recent version. However, in that case I would also expect to find something in the eventviewer log. The server is joined to a domain and made secondary domain controller, the SQL Server service is running as `NT Service\MSSQLSERVER`. This setup worked for about three years, the problems started recently.

Comment: Since you seem not to believe me that there are accounts that are in the "NT Service" "Domain": this is my setup: https://i.imgur.com/CS9Oo5A.png and this is the default in SQL Server install: http://www.sqlcoffee.com/images/SQLServer2014_0005/SQLServer2014_0005_0014.png

Comment: Would you mind running `gpresult /H gpreport.html` from an elevated command prompt on the server in question and then upload it somewhere I can look it over when you get a chance. The file output name will be gpreport.html and this is the file I'd like to review once you run it from an elevated command prompt while signed onto the SQL Server. I assume you are signed on as a domain account as well but I'll take whatever you get regardless to look it over for you.... You can use `gpresult /H C:\folder\path\gpreport.html` and change the path so you know where to drop it.